# Portable Monitors bigger than 15 inch

Tags: monitors, portable

I`m searching for portable monitors bigger than 15 inch. When I enter this to Amazon or Google Shopping, the monitors shown are not really portable or too small: They are thick.

I don't want to use it in a train or something. Just take it with me, and use it at another desk, witch electrical connection. Just want to have a portable programming workspace when I`m in another city. For that I need my Laptop + 2 Monitors.

So I want a portable monitor which is:

- At least 20inch
- Thin
- With a kind of protection, like tablets have it. To put it above the screen when it is in my backpack
- Battery not needed
- Touch not needed

Does somebody have a suggestion.

Comment: 20 years ago, having a big monitor meant that you have a lot of money to waste. Everything was optimized for small monitors, the de factor standard was a 14" and 1024x768px. Then, monitors became hugely more cheap. And then... the mobile world appeared. And now, if you want to buy a phone with a larger screen of 7", it will be a big problem. If you need to buy one over 11"... you won't find. Quite a psychotic world. Good luck for the hunt!

Comment: 20 inches? I'd say it's not so portable then ;) I know only Gechic On-Lap 2101H (21"). I have Gechihc 15.6" and I'd say it is quite big. Also You can look at some chinese brands, e.g. Johnwill, Uperfect, they sell 17-19" portable monitors.

Comment: @MikhailV As portable as possible for a 20 inch screen :) - I mean, it should be possible to put it in a Bag, and it should not have a stand which is bad to store. As I said: I don\`t want to use it in a train or something, just carry it easily from a to b in a trolley case.
The GeChick looks like it fits my use case, but it does not seem to be available for ordering.
It`s a bit strange, that 15inch is the maximum for that portable screens. There is no 18 or 20 inch screen available when I search it in Google Shopping or Amazon

Comment: You are right Gechic 21" is not available yet. Yes most portable displays are 15.6". I've seen a 18" display (Johnwill) on Aliexpress, but I personally would not expect quality product there. So probably wait till Gechic 21" starts to sell, at least it is more or less known brand.  Also if you are into DIY you could buy HDMI-LVDS converter  and buy a laptop display and improvise a portable monitor from it somehow.

Comment: Found two 17" screens:
https://www.amazon.de/G-STORY-Tragbarer-Monitor-Portable-Gaming/dp/B08B84MXFX/ref=sr_1_5?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&dchild=1&keywords=Portable+Monitor+-+17.3+Inch+1080P&qid=1598376042&sr=8-5
https://www.amazon.de/ASUS-XG17AHP-integrierter-Adaptive-Sync-Micro-HDMI/dp/B089VVDW5Q/ref=sr_1_7?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&dchild=1&keywords=Portable+Monitor+-+17.3+Inch+1080P&qid=1598376042&sr=8-7

Better than nothing, but quiet expensive...

Comment: Ok, there is more coming: Banggood PORPOISE-HT-1730XT-17
https://de.banggood.com/PORPOISE-HT-1730XT-17_3-Inch-1080P-Type-C-Portable-Computer-Monitor-Gaming-Display-Screen-for-Smartphone-Tablet-Laptop-Game-Consoles-p-1666078.html

Comment: G-STORY: out of stock - ASUS: expensive (550 euro, because of 240 Hz gamer panel) - PORPOISE: gambling (it seems that there might be a few dead pixels)

Comment: ASUS VZ229HE - not dedicated portable, but at least "slim"

Comment: From the ASUS VZxx9HE series the 22" version seems to be out of stock (almost) every where in Europe.

Answer (score 2):

I do have a suggestion because you didn't mention price. The Asus PQ22UC is the best in this category I've seen and I've been researching this for a [decade](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/1080p-travel-monitor.603212/) now. It has a super neat folding stand which lifts it off the table and it's thin as a blade. The price is a whole another problem. I dearly wish a monitor in this physical format was available with a cheaper panel. A much, *much* cheaper panel at that. You could knock off a zero from the price and it still would be expensive.

Currently I fly with the Sharp LL-201A in my carry on, any old tripod you can find with a removable ballhead and the [K&M 19685](https://www.k-m.de/en/products/multimedia-equipment/holders/19685-adapter-for-screens-black/19685-300-55) adapter, the only even remotely affordable VESA - to -tripod  preferably in checked in luggage but it fits in carry on too, it's just awkward. GearGrip makes good protective carry bags.

Edit: this answer just got outdated. Gechic has released the On-Lap 2101H in Asian markets and support told me they plan to release it in North America in 3Q 2021 as component shortage allows. Alas it does not have VESA mounting holes -- which are necessary to raise the monitor to an ergonomic height using a tripod but there are cheap kits to adapt any monitor to VESA (for example from Mount-It).

Comment: Thank you. The Asus PQ22UC seems great. But 4000 €? Whuuut? Is it made of gold? :) - Strange, that there are so less products in this category.

Comment: The PQ22UC panel is a highly color accurate OLED panel. Those are ... not cheap.   Also, check my answer now, it has the absolute latest developments: I got an answer from Gechic regarding the 2101H availability less than 24 hours ago.

Comment: Great, thank you. When it is available worldwide, I will mark your answer as the correct answer.

Comment: @user1383029 GeChic just emailed me it's available in the US.